# Initializing and Navigating a char[][]

Tags: c++, memory-management

Let's say I have a char[2][3] named charPP, 2 rows, 3 columns.

1. What is the best way to initialize the whole thing with dummy data?
2. How would I change the value of a certain cell? For example, make it so the pointer to the last column in each row is a nullptr?
3. What would happen if I did a `reinterpret_cast<char**>(charPP[0])`?

Sorry if this is generic or vague, I'm just looking for some basic understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `char charPP[2][3] = { 0 };`
2. `charPP[i][j] = 0;` `char[0][2] = 0; char[1][2] = 0;`
3. Possible mayhem since you're casting a char value(-128 to 127) to a `char**`.

Comment: If you want to initialize it to all zeros just use `char charPP[2][2] = { 0 };`

Comment: I meant to ask about char**, but typed it wrong. :/ So I asked the wrong question, but you answered it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As for case number 3, I guess you really means `reinterpret_cast<char**>(charPP)`? Well you simply can't access an array of arrays as a pointer to pointer, because the memory layout is not compatible.

Lets say you have an array `char a[2][2]`, it's memory layout would be

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

However, if you use pointer to pointer (i.e. `char **`), which you used as the above array, it would look like this:

```
+------+------+-----+
| a[0] | a[1] | ... |
+------+------+-----+
  |      |
  |      V
  |      +---------+---------+---------+-----+
  |      | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | a[1][2] | ... |
  |      ----------+---------+---------+-----+
  V
  +---------+---------+---------+-----+
  | a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] | ... |
  +---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

---

For case number 2, while it's true that you can use an array as a pointer (arrays decays to pointers), it's still an array so you can't make parts of it "point" to null. Lets take the example above, with `char a[2][2]`, you can't do `a[0] = nullptr`.

---

In case number 1, you do know how to access a single cell for a simple (one-dimensional) array don't you? It's just the same for multi-dimensional arrays, as long as you remember that you have an *array of arrays*.

Comment: Ahh, I suppose this was a flawed question then. I'll rename this to be about char 2D arrays, and reword and ask another question for a char**. Thank you.